# Pass parameters for each browser using Protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

Just got started with Protractor for E2E testing.

I want to pass parameters (login and password) for each instance of chrome selenium server.
I want test the same spec file with different user account in parallel.

This is my conf.js :

```
 capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'args': ['--disable-web-security']
        },
        count: 10
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`onPrepare`-method](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L406) of Protractor for that. If multiple capabilities are being run, this will run once per capability. You can add data to the browser-object that you can use during your execution.

What you can do is something like this

```js
// A JSON file or something
var login = {
  "chrome": {
    "user": "usernameChrome",
    "pass": "passwordChrome"
  },
  "firefox": {
    "user": "usernameFirefox",
    "pass": "passwordFirefox"
  }
};


// in your config
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  multiCapabilities: [{
      'browserName': 'chrome'
    },
    {
      'browserName': 'firefox'
    }
  ],

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['example_spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  },

  onPrepare: function() {
    return browser.getCapabilities()
      .then((capabilities) => {
        // Get the current browser you are using
        browser.browserName = capabilities.get('browserName').toLowerCase();
        // Add the user and pass to the browser-object
        browser.user = login[browser.browserName].user;
        browser.pass = login[browser.browserName] pass;
      });
  }
};

// In your spec
describe('logon', function() {
  it('should logon', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.example.com');

    element(by.model('user')).sendKeys(browser.user);
    element(by.model('pass')).sendKeys(browser.pass);
    element(by.tagName('button')).click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this with [Protractor's `params`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L462) on the command line. For example, you can start each test with a different username/password like this:

```
protractor conf.js --params.username user1 --params.password password1
```

Then, in your test, you would use them something like this:

```
logIntoMyApp(browser.params.username, browser.params.password);
```

You can also set defaults in your config file (see the docs for details).

Comment: Thinks Brine for your replay. but in my case, I want pass params for each instance created. I used count attribut in my conf.js `count: 10`. So for all chrome instance will use user1 as login and password1 as password. I want for example the first instance use Login1 and Password1, and the second use Login2 and Password2 ....

Comment: In that case, your question doesn't have enough information. I suggest fleshing it out more, and include what you're really trying to accomplish. Eg. are you trying to do load testing? Good luck.